# MVC java, can controllers listen to other controllers? Must all controllers be instantiated initally?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, structure

I am new to using MVC in an object oriented context. Other questions on this topic failed to answer controller specific questions.

My idea of MVC is controllers hold their associated views, (using the observer design pattern the controller listens to action events in the view). However im my application in my initial 'start up menu view' the controller listens and handles 'register' and 'login' events. I also have a button  called 'Quick build' which bypasses register and login. This 'quick build' button fires an event to use a DIFFERENT controller/view. The logical solution would be to instantiate the new controller and display its view as the event when the button is pushed. However it seems more MVC like to have my second controller listen to the first which would require it to be already instantiated. In that case i would instantiate all controllers in the main method and pass their listeners (including my second controller listening to the first for the 'quick build' event.)

Does any of this even matter!? Or am I thinking way too deeply into this? I ask this because im not sure of how rigid the MVC architecture needs to be.

PS all OOP(Object Orientated Programming) MVC tutorials I have seen are basic and don't demonstrate how to handle more than 1 controller so  I haven't been able to find this information myself. This question and its answers will be beneficial to beginner software developers who want to understand high level concepts of MVC in  a OOP contect

Comment: Since you say there is a *quick build* option in the first view, then its controller should handle it and fire a navigation to the second view where the second controller will process and fill the second view.

Comment: Ok I see so the second controller does not listen to the first controller, the first controller should display the new view and and the second controller then handles any actions taken in the new view. I do follow you but how about instantiation. would you have the instance of the second controller instantiated as part of the first controllers action, or would it be better to have all controllers and listeners instantiated at the beginning of the program? I will implement this immediatly, thanks for the knowledge.

Comment: That will depend on your design, so there isn't an exact answer for your second question. In case of web applications, the Servlets (the controllers) are created when initializing the application and then just being reused everytime.

Comment: Oh I see, so generally it depends on the type of application and we can choose to implement these specifics however we choose? I hope this is useful to anyone new reading this: So a would a valid conclusion to my questions be; Instantiation depends on your specific application. MVC architecture isn't specific on such details. As long as you have Controllers listening to events in views, data encapsulated in models, and views ONLY display and retrieve data, then  you are properly using MVC?

Comment: Your last statement is right, it depends on the application design.

Comment: Thanks Luggi Mendoza. Our discussion will now forever be of use to people. I appreciate the time.